# sql - SELECT MAX row of records WHERE records not in range

Tags: sql, sql-server

My user_trans table looked like this

```
ID    User_ID   User_No   Date_From     Date_To
1      00001    KJH789    2013-03-02   2013-03-05
2      00001    KJH789    2013-03-07   2013-03-30
3      00001    KJH789    2013-02-28   2013-03-01
4      00001    KJH789    2013-02-01   2013-02-15
5      00026    RTW763    2013-02-01   2013-02-15
6      00026    RTW763    2013-01-01   2013-01-15
```

I need to select max record of users that date_to does not falls within the selected date ranges. Selected date 1/3/2013 - 15/3/2013

If I wrote my query as

```
SELECT USER_ID,
       MAX(DATE_TO) AS DATE_TO
  FROM USER_TRANS
  WHERE DATE_TO <= CONVERT (datetime, (({d '2013-03-15' })+1)
  GROUP BY USER_ID
```

It will select as below

```
 User_ID    Date_To
  00001    2013-03-05
  00026    2013-02-15
```

Since some of records user_ID 0001 falls within the range of selected date, I do not want any of it records appear in the result. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is EMPLOYEE_ID just a typo? It is not mentioned in your sample data.

Comment: @Alex I'm guessing EMPLOYEE_ID is a typo for USER_ID, based on the query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
SELECT USER_ID,
   MAX(DATE_TO) AS DATE_TO
FROM USER_TRANS WHERE 
USER_ID IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_TRANS EXCEPT
SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_TRANS 
WHERE DATE_TO BETWEEN CONVERT (datetime, (({d '2013-03-01' })) AND CONVERT (datetime, (({d '2013-03-15' }))
)
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? I can't remember SQL Server having `MINUS` keyword. The question specifically mentions sql-server tag

Comment: This doesn't compile in sql server.

Comment: Although you could rewrite this query as 
    SELECT USER_ID,
    MAX(DATE_TO) AS DATE_TO
    FROM USER_TRANS WHERE 
    USER_ID NOT IN (
         SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_TRANS 
         WHERE DATE_TO BETWEEN 
                 CONVERT (datetime, (({d '2013-03-01' })) AND 
                 CONVERT (datetime, (({d '2013-03-15' }))
         )
    GROUP BY USER_ID

Comment: That also doesn't compile - how about this: SELECT USER_ID, MAX(DATE_TO) AS DATE_TO FROM USER_TRANS WHERE USER_ID NOT IN ( SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_TRANS WHERE DATE_TO BETWEEN CONVERT (datetime, (({d '2013-03-01' }))) AND CONVERT (datetime, (({d '2013-03-15' })) )) GROUP BY USER_ID

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER_ID,
   MAX(DATE_TO) AS DATE_TO
FROM USER_TRANS u1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM USER_TRANS u2 WHERE u2.user_id = u1.user_id 
     and date_to BETWEEN '3/1/2013' AND '3/15/2013')
GROUP BY USER_ID
```